# No triggers getting returned from Ambient data Helper

Tags: dxa, ambient-data-framework, experience-optimization, dxa2.2

I have a .NET web application using DXA 2.2 framework. I tried to use Smart Target capability, and I have installed all the desired components (Elastic search, XO management, XO query, services extension for Deployer, Session Content Service, XO module etc.). I created a Promotion and it appears fine on the Page when I set the Triggers to be "Always trigger" in Targeting section in CMS.

However if I try to use "browser based" Trigger for this Promotion then the Promotion is not returned from the smart-target query. While trying to find the root cause, I found that `AmbientDataHelper.GetTriggers(claimStore)` returns empty string for triggers. When I inspected the passed Claim Store then I saw it has some values for claims in it, still `AmbientDataHelper.GetTriggers(claimStore)` is returning empty string.

During further investigation I found that all keys from the passed Claim Store looks like:

[image]

Can you please help me understand what could be the potential root cause for this and how to fix that?

Comment: I’m not sure how to interpret that screen shot. Are those claim values? For which claim types?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. These are all the keys from the claim store. When system calls AmbientDataHelper.GetTriggers(claimStore) method then it passes the claim store. The screenshot above shows the keys (lowercased Uri from claim store) from the passed claim store.

Comment: So they keys are called `case “taf:x:y:z”:` ?!

Comment: Yes, they are. I have checked the code in ambient data helper and these values in picutre are driven from statement equivalent to IDictionary<Uri, object> all = claimStore.GetAll(); all .Select(a=>a.Key.ToLowerCase()); this code.

Comment: Are you sure the key names aren’t the part of the string in quotes?  If so, it would be interesting to see the value of the `taf:claim:ambientdata:definedtriggertypes` claim.

Comment: Aha, Now I understood you. Yes key names are only what is included in the quotes. so key names are like "taf:session:id". Please ignore "case" caption , this caption is not part of key.

Comment: This is fixed now. I was missing reference for session jat and session_cartridge_conf.xml file in content service. Post adding that I am getting the triggers. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Please Answer your own Question, then.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by referencing session_cartridge.jar and session_cartridge_conf.xml file in content service. Details about how to reference session cartride can be found at https://docs.sdl.com/792149/602448/sdl-tridion-sites-9/adding-the-session-cartridge-to-support-footprints. Post referencing mentioned Jar and XML file, I can now see the OOTB claims present in claims store.